# Rspec Model Association Test not working on model subclass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails

```
class Proofreader < Role

  has_many :proofreading_jobs,   :class_name => 'ProofreadingJob',   :foreign_key => 'proofreader_id'

end

class ProofreadingJob < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :proofreader, class_name: 'Role', foreign_key: :proofreader_id, optional: true
  belongs_to :client,      class_name: 'Role', foreign_key: :client_id
  end

class Role < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :user

end

proofreaders factory:

    FactoryBot.define do
      factory :proofreader do
        type { 'Proofreader'}
        hourly_rate { 15 }
        association :user, factory: :employee_user

        factory :proofreader_with_work_events do

          after :create do |proofreader|
            create(:user_event, :recurring_mwf, user: proofreader.user)
          end

        end
      end
    end
```

spec/model_roles/proofreader_spec.rb

```
RSpec.describe 'Proofreader', type: :model do

  describe "Associations" do
    it { should have_many(:proofreading_jobs) }
  end

end
```

Test fails with:

```
Failure/Error: it { should have_many(:proofreading_jobs) }
       expected Associations to respond to `has_many?`
```

Clearly the class ProofreadingJob has the association there. How can I write this test so it passes?

Comment: Can you share `ProofreadingJob` model  associations ?

Comment: As per request I have added the ProofreadingJob class

Comment: Can you please try with this `it { should have_many(:proofreading_jobs).class_name('ProofreadingJob').with_foreign_key('proofreader_id') }`

Comment: Do you have `Factory` for `Proofreader`  model ? And Configure [shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers#configuration) correctly

Comment: Tried your suggestion and got: undefined method `class_name' for #<RSpec::Matchers::BuiltIn::Has:0x007fdde8aa7918>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to define a subject - the object your tests will interact with.

It can be something like this:

```
describe "Associations" do
  expect(ProofreadingJob.new).to be_valid # ProofreadingJob.new is subject here
end
```

When you got the understanding of subject you can test the association. It can be like this:

```
RSpec.describe ProofreadingJob, type: :model do
  it { should have_many(:proofreading_jobs) }
end
```

Here's the subject is defined by Rspec from `ProofreadingJob, type: :model` line. Please note that `ProofreadingJob` is not a string but actual model name (class), so Rspec will know how to make subject from that model.

To use such syntax you have to add [`shoulda-matchers`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers)

Comment: Thanks megas, I have updated my spec adding in the type: :model and I get NoMethodError:
       undefined method `reflect_on_association' for String:Class. I do have the shoulda-matcheres gem installed.

Comment: I figured it out with what you explained in your answer. I had RSpec.describe 'ProofreadingJob', type: :model in quotation so it saw it as a string. I removed the quotations and now it works. Thanks for your explanation.